# Custom validator to prevent overlapping appointments in Rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I need help writing a custom validation to prevent overlapping appointments in a Rails 4 app. I'm coding this app to teach myself Ruby & Rails. While researching the issue, I discovered a gem called ValidatesOverlap, but I want to write my own validator for learning purposes.

My Appointment model has an "appointment_at" column of the datetime datatype and a "duration" column of the time datatype.  The Appointment model has a "has_many :through" association with Member and Trainer models.  Appointments:

```
belongs_to :member
belongs_to :trainer
```

Existing validations in the Appointment model include:

```
validates :member, uniqueness: {scope: :appointment_at, message: "is booked already"}
validates :trainer, uniqueness: {scope: :appointment_at, message: "is booked already"}
```

The custom validator needs to prevent members or trainers from scheduling overlapping appointments. Right now, I can prevent "duplicate appointments" from being saved to the database, but can't stop "overlapping" ones.  For example, if trainer_1 is booked for a 1 hour appointment with member_1 which starts at 7:00 am, my model validations prevent member_2 from booking an appointment with trainer_1 for 7:00 am.  However, I have no current means of preventing member_2 from scheduling a session with trainer_1 for 7:01 am!  I'm working with two attributes:  "appointment_at," which is the start time and "duration" which is the total time of an appointment.  I'd prefer to keep those attributes/columns if I can easily calculate "end time" from the "appointment_at" and "duration" values. I haven't figured out how to do that yet :)

I'd appreciate any thoughts or suggestions about how I can approach solving the problem of overlapping appointments (without using a gem). Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago. You need a scope `:overlapping`, that reads overlapping appointments for an appointment and a validator to check. This example is for a PostgreSQL DB. You have to adjust it for your DB, if you're using another DB.

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :trainer

  validate :overlapping_appointments

  scope :overlapping, ->(a) {
     where(%q{ (appointment_at, (appointment_at + duration)) OVERLAPS (?, ?) }, a.appointment_at, a.appointment_to)
    .where(%q{ id != ? }, a.id)
    .where(trainer_id: a.trainer.id)
  }

  def find_overlapping
    self.class.overlapping(self)
  end

  def overlapping?
    self.class.overlapping(self).count > 0
  end

  def appointment_to
    (appointment_at + duration.hour.hours + duration.min.minutes + duration.sec.seconds).to_datetime
  end

  protected

  def overlapping_appointments
    if overlapping?
      errors[:base] << "This appointment overlaps with another one."  
    end
  end

end
```

Give it a try and let me know, if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks Hiasinho!  I'm using PostgresSQL for my development, testing, and deployment databaes. I'll give it a try at my earliest opportunity; I'll let you now how it goes.

Comment: Running the code causes an "undefined method" error:
NoMethodError in AppointmentsController#create 
undefined method `and' for        #<Appointment::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000006223188>
Extracted source (around line #29):

Line 29 is the following code: .and.where(trainer_id: a.trainer.id)

It appears Rails 4 is objecting to ".and," saying it is an undefined method.

I removed ".and" so see what happens, and the model prevents all appointments from being saved, raising the objection that the appointment overlaps with another one.  Any ideas about how to diagnose and fix the problem?

Comment: I am doing this freehanded at the moment. I made some changed to the code. Added a WHERE to exclude the current appointment (if persisted) and added the `overlapping?` method. Try using byebug for debugging. Do you have specs for that or do you test it in the console?

Comment: Hiasinho, the new code works as expected when a member tries to schedule an overlapping appointment with a trainer. The trainer scoping is not a problem. Thanks for all of your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: I discovered an odd case with the validation. On CREATE, the validation does not prevent an "overlappping" appointment that begins before the start time of an existing appointment.  However, if I EDIT & resave the still overlapping apppointment, the validation kicks in and stops it from being saved to the DB. What could be causing this strange behavior?  Could it be controller related, because it appears to affect the creation and editing of overlaping appointments. I'm trying troubleshoot this, but puzzled. This is a great learning experience!  Any ideas?

Comment: Try going to the console (`rails c` on your command prompt) and try it out programmatically. Add byebug to your Gemfile"s test group. Then write `byebug` somewhere in your code to set a breakpoint ([Rails debug guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)). Type `help` for a command help. Write some tests in Rspec and try debugging them. This will get you going for a while. If I find some time, I'll try that in an application.

Comment: I installed byebug to debug the issue. I'm using Rspec. My Appointment Controller spec was passing before the overlap validation code. Now it has 2 failures:

   Failure/Error: post :create, {:appointment => invalid_attributes}, valid_session
     NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

    Failure/Error: post :create, {:appointment => invalid_attributes}, valid_session
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Something is amiss between controller & model. The validation doesn't work on creation of appointments, but works on update.  What do you think?

Comment: This is going off-topic now. I can't give you advice for your test suite without knowing a whole lot more about your app setup. Sorry. You can also find my on irc #rubyonrails if you want more help.

Comment: Okay. I appreciate the help you gave me. I'll continue to try to figure it out.  Thanks again!