# Combining 2 fields for knowing a datetime exists in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently working on a personal project in rails with date/time objects. I came to a point where I have an appointment model with 2 attributes:

```
- starts_at datetime
- ends_at datetime
```

I previously had the constraint of only working with half hours which made it fairly easy to validate by looking if the starts_at datetime was already present.

But now I decided I also want appointments to take up to one hour. My question now is: How can I validate if a datetime is already in use in a performant way. Currently I'm looping over every record and check if my "proposed" datetime is between the start and the enddate.

Comment: Can't you just do Appointment.where("starts_at > ? AND ends_at < ?", first_time, second_time)

Comment: I guess so. If I do it like that won't it suffer when you have like 10000 records? (I could be wrong)

Comment: I believe this was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27837273/2280625).